# Timeline aggregation sort by drop-down glitch

Tags: facebook-graph-api, action, aggregation, facebook-timeline

I created an object (book) and an action (add), and I am now trying to create the aggregation for the two. I created the aggregation, and clicked on the "Sort by" dropdown. The options looked like this:

Most Recent <- currently selected
Most Recent Add
Favorite Add
Custom...

I thought "cool, I want Most Recent Add". However, I can't even click on that. I can click on "Favorite Add", though. After I click on it, "Most Recent Add" goes gray, and "Favorite" shows up in the selection.

There are two issues here. First, there is inconsistency of wording. Is "Most Recent" the same as "Most Recent Add, and "Favorite" the same as "Favorite Add"? If they are there should be only a single option. IF not, then why does clicking on one result in the other being shown? Second, why is there an option that is at first shown as valid, and then is later greyed out?

Answer (score 0):

Recent is greyed out for me as well, I think it is only applicable to a certain objects.